# Image recognition, separate lines

Tags: java, image, image-processing

I need to separate lines from each other and make an array of coordinates for each graphic. The problem is (see the red circled section on the pic) some graphics overlap, and i don't know how to write a program that will find this overlaps and separate them. (Now we think that lines only touch each other not cross.)

[image: Squiggly lines]

@Rethunk i maked thinning and got this result.
[after thinning](http://i45.tinypic.com/24gq4c0.jpg)

Comment: Why don't you construct the graph correctly instead ?

Comment: I have no idea how graph can help me in this.Is it possible to make graph from this image or what do you mean?

Comment: This is a plot of something, just construct it without overlapping lines. That is what I meant.

Comment: @mmgp I was assuming the original data that was used to generate the plot is not available. Like for example having seismic data in black-and-white graphical form only (instead of arrays of coordinates): [an example in color from Millersville University](http://snowball.millersville.edu/~cws/seismic/archives/2013/January/Global_East-West/2013012700.gif).

Comment: @FreekdeBruijn well, but in that linked image there is no overlapping. They made it right :)

Comment: @mmpg Yes, that linked image is easy. But with very expensive paper, without color ink and an earthquake you could get the image above... ;-)

Comment: @FreekdeBruijn was right, i get this image without any other information its seismic data, if i can i'll make this graphic without overlapping)

Answer (score 1):

If you know that the lines are initially separated, you could keep track of them going from left to right. For each line the top and bottom y-coordinates gradually change, while the x-coordinate is increasing. For each pixel you go to the right, you could start at the average y-coordinate and move up and down to find the new top and bottom y-coordinates for each line.

When two lines touch, their top and bottom y-coordinates will be the same. This can be detected by comparing the coordinates for lines that are next to each other. So lets say for example, line 4 and 5 overlap at a certain point. For these lines, you know which one is the higher line (4) and the lower line (5). Lets say yTopOverlap = 130 and yBottomOverlap = 160. We could divide the pixels between the two lines. In this case, make yTop 130 and yBottom 145 for line 4 and make yTop 146 and yBottom 160 for line 5. When the lines separate again, it is no longer necessary to modify their y-coordinates.

Comment: I think this idea can work for two lines indeed. The problem I see is that, even in this example, there is at least one position where the lines 4, 5, and 6 touch and the idea doesn't apply when more than 2 lines overlap.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I think more than two lines could be handled by dividing the overlap in three or more segments. There's also quite a challenge with line 5: it has a few interruptions.

Comment: Some dynamic-programing (Viterbi) could help here

Comment: To follow up Freek's idea: have you tried first thinning the image? A few other notes: (1) the vertical extent of a connected region of black pixels is longer in the region of crossed lines, which can help you identify them; (2) there should be just one contour-following path [of a thinned image] from one end of a line to another; following the crossed lines results in two or more possible terminations; (3) a connected components algorithm could identify individual connected regions, and then you could filter connected regions by height to identify potential crossed lines.

Comment: @Rethunk point (1) is a fallacy, think of a letter "I" not overlapped with anything else, now think of the symbols "_" and "-" overlapped. This problem extends to the point (3). Point (2) can help, but what is actually interesting is detecting the bifurcations. The problem then is getting, at least, a properly pruned thinned image.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow, mmgp. Where would there be something resembling an isolated "I" in the sample image posted by Neo?